# Dynamically create a html structure in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently facing an issue with vue.js where I want to dynamically create html tags inside a v-for loop. The usecase is as follows:

The resulting html should look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
...
```

The array I'm iterating over only contains the item elements:

```
[
    {
         name: 1
    },
    {
         name: 2
    },
    {
         name: 3
    },
    {
         name: 4
    }
]
```

The standard v-for loop would look like this:

```
<div class="item" v-for="item in items">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

But obviously the wrapper elements are missing. How do I include them? The only solution I can think of is to create a computed variable and nest the items there and then iterate over the nested version. The computed variable would look something like this:

```
[
    {
         items: [
             {
                  name: 1
             },
             {
                  name: 2
             }
         ]
    },
    {
         items: [
             {
                  name: 3
             },
             {
                  name: 4
             }
         ]
    }
]
```

But I really don't want to do that, because it's bulky and not very nice. The perfect solution would be to organize the structure somehow in the template, like I would do it with php for example. (Opening and closing the html tag of the wrapper div at the appropriate times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution based on your example. Hopefully you can adapt it to fit your needs.

It looks like you're chunking your array of items into groups of two. I created a `filter` to do that chunking:

```
Vue.filter('chunk', function (value, size) {
  return _.chunk(value, size); // using lodash
})
```

Then I used that filter to create a nested `v-for` loop:

```
<div v-for="group in items | chunk 2" class="wrapper">
  <div v-for="item in group" class="item">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The outer loop iterates the 'chunks' and the inner loop iterates each item in a chunk.

Here's a full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t597sefq/) example.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple solution, but basically it just creates the last code block I added as an example in my question. Initially, I didn't want to do it like that, mainly because it is not very flexible and can't be adapted very easily to similar problems. Thanks nevertheless, because I think I will go with your solution in this case.

Comment: Tried your fiddle but its not working. Does this still works with vue2?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the jsfiddle. This solution only works with Vue 1.x; I don't think filters can be used in as many places in Vue 2.x. You might be able to achieve something similar with a computed property in Vue 2.